# Angular - change image according to screen size (ng-srcset)

Tags: angularjs, resize-image

I'm creating a responsive web site and I'm trying to set an image according to the screen size. If the screen is wide I'll set a bigger image, if screen is smaller a smaller image.

To achieve that, I'm using `ng-srcset` like this:

`<img ng-src="css/images/1280-iphone5.png" ng-srcset="css/images/iphone5-mobile.png 640w" />`

This code works but from time to time, when I reload the website in my computer, the "default" picture (1280-iphone5.png) **is displayed but much bigger than the normal size.**

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: If you are not binding anything on your image urls I see no point in using `ng-src` nor `ng-srcset`, please try it out using the plain `src` and `srcset` and let me know if that works.

Comment: I tried to use `src` and `srcset` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [psResponsive](https://github.com/randallmeeker/psResponsive).

You can configure screen sizes using `psResponsiveConfig`

```
angular.module('psResponsive', [])
  .value('psResponsiveConfig', {
    sizes: [{
        name: 'small',
        minWidth: 640
    }, {
        name: 'medium',
        minWidth: 880
    }, {
        name: 'large',
        minWidth: 1024
    }]
});
```

And use these sizes' names in your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to do what I want perfectly (it's a good option if i can't fix the error) but first I will give it a try to understand what's wrong with `srcset`